# In WatiN how to wait until postback is complete

Tags: asp.net, watin

in WatiN how can I wait until postback is complete.

For example:

```
// Postback response modifies update panel elsewhere on page
browser.Text("id").TypeText("asd"); 

// WatiN doesn't wait until postback is completed (what code should I replace it with?).
browser.WaitUntilComplete();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WaitUntilComplete doesn't recognize ajax calls. See this article (search on WaitForAsyncPostBackToComplete) on how to inject some code to make that work as well: [WatiN, Ajax and some Extension Methods](http://richallen.blogspot.com/2008/08/watin-ajax-and-some-extension-methods.html)

HTH,
Jeroen

Comment: Thank you. That exactly what I found later on. It's strange how I didn't came around this article in first 3 days of searching

Answer (score 11):

You could check if IE is busy rather than complete.

```
while (((SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass)(_ie.InternetExplorer)).Busy)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Comment: It's sad that I can't mark two answers as correct but I will keep in mind your trick as well for future use

Comment: +1 I was a bit sceptic, but this works flawlessly with Ajax! Thank you for this tip! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned WaitForComplete is fine for a loading page, but doesn't work for Ajax calls.

Here's a very simple solution that works well for my situation where I expect a specific element to appear... perhaps... eventually. It simply loops until **elementID** exists on a page, or times out after 20 seconds:

```
DateTime _startWait = DateTime.Now;
while (_startWait.AddMilliseconds(20000) > DateTime.Now && !WatiNbrowser.Elements.Exists(elementID))
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }
```

Comment: Since you are in a STA Thread why are you calling `Application.DoEvents()` ?

Comment: Indeed that is redundant. This was some old code from back when I first started C# and didn't know better.