# Execute JavaScript code to get the log from console using selenium webdriver or WatiN

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver, watin

(Sorry for being a bit descriptive)
I wanted to wait for a page to load completely but after searching on Google it seems that browsers react differently, when we try to use readyState or onLoad.
Also, for application I am working on, it seems that a particular log message (`"TNP is ready"`) appears in console (chrome console or IE developer tool console), when the required page is loaded.
My plan is to execute a small JavaScript code on the browser, using Selenium WebDriver C# and WatiN C# (IE), to get this message from the console log.

Can this be done? Can I get the Last Log generated by console.log ?
Because when I execute the script it might happen that the message is already gone or yet to come. I need to fire it repeatedly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This question, while not exactly a duplicate of [In WatiN how to wait until postback is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979610/in-watin-how-to-wait-until-postback-is-complete), is probably caused by the same thing.

The `browser.WaitUntilComplete()` method will wait for the page to finish loading, but if you have AJAX going on in the background as the page is loading then `WaitUntilComplete` won't do the trick.

From my research, there is no way to get log messages from the browser console unless you include some JavaScript to mirror the console and overwrite `window.console` and provide a mechanism for inspecting console messages.

```
(function(win) {

var console = win.console;

if (!console)
    throw new Error("This browser does not support a debug console");

var mirror = {},
    data = {};

var toString = Object.prototype.toString,
    mirrorMethod = function(key) {
        data[key] = [];

        return function() {
            data[key].push(arguments);
            console[key].apply(console, arguments);
        };
    };

for (var key in console) {
    if (toString.call(console[key]) == "[object Function]") {
        mirror[key] = mirrorMethod(key);
    }
}

win.console = mirror;

win.consoleMirror = {
    getData: function(key) {
        return data[key] || [];
    }
};

}(this));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyhLw0to/

And to use:

```
console.log("foo");
alert(consoleMirror.getData("log")[0][0]);
```

An alternative is to grab an element using WatiN that you need to interact with, and call `WaitUntilExists`:

```
var button = browser.Button("buttonIdThatDoesNotExistYet");

button.WaitUntilExists();
button.Click();
```

This way you don't have to hack the debug console, or hack `XMLHttpRequest` to infer when AJAX is done. Your tests will attempt to wait for elements to appear on the page before acting upon them. Test failures will be slower, but your tests should be more robust.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Even I wanted to add `WaitUntilExists` but the problem is I am working on a common framework, which is used by others, so it is bit difficult to wait for one particular element. I cannot ask user to put `WaitUntilExists` each time, it should be generic. Generally some frames/iframes take time to load. I will try the JavaScript code and update.

Comment: Can you describe more about this framework maybe? Are you using SpecFlow or just hand writing these tests in C#?

Comment: I am not using any unit testing framework. Common framework is nothing but extensions on top of WatiN Core framework. These are just functions which are used by different teams by including the DLL file. I have written functions like `SwitchToPopup`, `SwitchToMainWindow`, etc. After doing some work on popup window, I submit it and switch back to main window. Now I want to wait on this main window before doing other work.